# Dúvida string aleatória com Javascript

Tags: javascript

Pessoal estou precisando retornar 2 strings aleatórias 'João' ou 'Maria' para implementar na seguinte tabela.. já dei uma pesquisada no Google, porem só consegui fazer o retorno dos números INTEIROS e não as strings.. Agradeço! 
Segue o código...

```
for(i = 1; i<=30; i++) {
var maximo = 5;
var a = parseInt(Math.random()*maximo+1);
var b = parseInt(Math.random()*maximo+1);
var name = // <= aqui vem a logica dos nomes!

table += '<tr><td>'+i+'</td>';
table += '<td>'+a+'</td>';
table += '<td>'+b+'</td>';
table += '<td>'+name+'</td>';
table += '<td>1</td>';
table += '<td>1</td>';
table += '<td>1</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: Gera um número entre 1 e 2. Se der um é João, 2 é Maria.

Comment: Boa alternativa, vou testar aqui...

Comment: Se ficar mais fácil par ou ímpar, você pode verificar se uma variável qualquer é par da seguinte forma. Suponha um número x, então x é par se `(x % 2) == 0` ou ímpar se `(x % 2) == 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue uma *alternativa* para retornar randomicamente as strings:

```js
function MariaOuJoao(){
  var opcoes = ["Joao","Maria"];
  alert(opcoes[Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : 1]);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="MariaOuJoao()">Random</button>
```

Comment: Obrigado Brother, consegui resolver com a sua resposta. grato!

Answer (score 1):

Chame esta função em "//aqui vem a lógica de nomes".

```
function pegaUmQualquer() {
    min = Math.ceil(0);
    max = Math.floor(1);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min === 0 ? "João" : "Maria";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução para *N* nomes, sem precisar de mudar mais no código.

Cria uma array com os nomes que queres usar e depois usas `Math.ceil(Math.random() * (nomes.length - 1))` como indice do elemento a buscar.

```js
var nomes = ['João', 'Maria', 'Antonio', 'Joana'];
var name = nomes[Math.ceil(Math.random() * (nomes.length - 1))];
console.log(name);
```

Comment: Está acontecendo um problema bizarro. Quando executo a primeira vez, funciona ok. Se eu executar uma segunda vez, o snippet não funciona e me redireciona para essa página: `https://stacksnippets.net/js`.

Comment: @Renan também me aconteceu, acho que é bug aqui no site. Vou esperar para ver se há em mais posts, e lanço o bug-report.

Comment: Tem horas que retorna `undefined` no `console.log`. Estranho não!?

Comment: @Renan o `undefined` foi erro meu porque estava a gerar numeros grandes demais :) Corrigi.